# Rings in Smoke Render - Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I'm building an animated logo where some text punches through the logo. However there are weird turbulence rings in the smoke that I can't get rid of. I have smoke domains on different layers (for each smoke color). All domains are set up identically other than the node color.
I also have a section of smoke that is hidden diagonally which makes no sense to me.
Any idea how I can solve these issues? I've tried baking the simulation and freeing the bake with no difference in how it is rendered.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the rings in the smoke were caused due to the fact that I had my 3 smoke domains positioned at exactly the same location and were the same size. I changed the size of each domain and their locations slightly which resulted in good smoke. I'm still not sure what caused the smoke to be hidden diagonally but that seemed to go away as well.